# Copying Visuals in PowerBI Dashboard

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to copy a visual from one page to another in my dashboard, and want to edit the DAX Expression linked to the visual. The trouble is when I edit the DAX for a visual on Page 2, it updates the one on page 1 as well. How do I de-link the formula to update it on Page 2?

Thanks,
Viswanath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you simply need to create two separate visuals in your report. One that displays the result evaluated by the first DAX code, one that displays the result evaluated by the second DAX code.